# ¿Como verificar si ya existe un producto con el mismo nombre ,y/o retornar el resultado si es exitoso o fallido?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, pdo

no se como hacer para verficar si ya existe un producto con ese nombre, eh 
probado otro metodo y no me sale,he buscado con pero me salen con otros metodos y 
otras conexiones,quiero mantener mi conexion por que todas estan basadas en ello,esto es mi clase conexión

```
<?php
class conexion
{   private static $dbName = 'capo' ;
    private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
    private static $dbUsername = 'root';
    private static $dbUserPassword = '';
    private static $cont  = null;
    //modificado
     public function __construct() {
        die('Init function is not allowed');
    }
    public static function connect()
    {
         // One connection through whole application
        if ( null == self::$cont )
        {
            try
            {
                self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword);

            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return self::$cont;
    }
     public static function disconnect()
    {
        self::$cont = null;
    }
}
?>
```

para registrar hago esto

```
 include '../funciones/conexion.php';
    $db = conexion::connect();
     $sql = "INSERT INTO tramites (nom_tramite, descripcion,requisito1,requisito2,requisito3,requisito4,requisito5,requisito6, imagen) VALUES ('$nom_tramite', '$descripcion','$requisito1', '$requisito2', '$requisito3', '$requisito4', '$requisito5', '$requisito6', '$image')";
            $db->query($sql);
```

para listar hago esto

```
   $pdo = conexion::connect();
                       $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM codigo c  left join tipo t on c.tipo_idtipo=t.idtipo where t.nombre_tipo = 'COLOR PRENDA' ORDER BY cod ASC  ";

                       $st = "<option   value='' selected disabled >-SELECCIONE-</option>";
                         foreach ($pdo->query($sql2) as $row2) {

                $st.= "<option   value='".$row2['cod']."' >".$row2['descripcion']."</option> ";
              }
```

pero no se como hacer para verficar si ya existe un producto con ese nombre, eh 
 probado otro metodo y no me sale,he buscado con pero me salen con otros metodos y 
otras conexiones,quiero mantener mi conexion por que todas estan basadas en ello, quirero reemplazar  este metodo,pero no es pdo,¿como lo haria con pdo basado en mi conexion?

```
 $cek = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE cod_pro='$cod'");

                if(mysqli_num_rows($cek) == 0){ echo "no existe"  ;    }else{  echo "ya existe"  ;       }
```

Comment: Estás mezclando entre PDO y mysqli. Son dos APIs distintas para consultar a la base de datos y no debes mezclar. Si conectas con PDO debes usar PDO para las consultas. Tampoco se entiende del todo lo que quieres hacer en tu código: primero hay una inserción y luego haces un select e intentas leer los datos de ese select y luego hay un segundo select. Es una lógica confusa la que presentas. No me parece normal tantas mezclas en un solo bloque de código. Propongo que intentes aclarar un poco cómo funciona tu programa para poder ayudarte.

Comment: hola @A.Cedano ,Ya edite mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

En PDO para comprobar si un registro existe, lo más seguro es lanzar un conteo de registros y recuperar ese valor con [`fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

Esto:

```
 $cek = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE cod_pro='$cod'");

                if(mysqli_num_rows($cek) == 0){ echo "no existe"  ;    }else{  echo "ya existe"  ;       }
```

Llevado a PDO, y además aplicando la buena práctica de consultas preparadas, sería:

```
/*
   Cambiamos la consulta por una que cuente y el valor lo cambiamos por un marcador, 
   porque es un riesgo enorme pasar valores a ejecución como estás haciendo,
   lee sobre Inyección SQL para que comprendas a qué me refiero
*/
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM producto WHERE cod_pro=?";

/*
  Pasamos el valor en el execute como array, para prevenir inyección SQL
*/
$stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute( array($cod) );

/*
  Obtenemos el valor de la columna que arroja la consulta
  y usamos un ternario para determinar qué mensaje mostrar
*/
$msg = ( $stmt->fetchColumn() > 0 ) ? "Existe" : "No existe";
echo $msg;
```

*That's all folks !*

Comment: Hola he probado con mi conexion <?php
include '../funciones/conexion.php';
   $db = conexion::connect();
        $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM producto WHERE cod_pro=?";
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql)->execute( array("1") );
      $msg = ( $stmt->fetchColumn() > 0 ) ? "Existe" : "No existe";
      echo $msg;
?>     ,y me sale el siguiente error,  Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\fusion\tinelo\cms\producto\reto.php on line 21 , deseo usar mi misma conexion.